# Aggregate function is counting each parent instead of the most recent one

Tags: sql, postgresql

Firstly I will show how my table structure looks:

```
table work
 id  | scid | starttime  | project_id
-----+------+------------+----------------
 293 |    1 | 2013-10-11 |      235
 294 |    2 | 2013-10-15 |      235
 295 |    5 | 2013-10-16 |      236
 296 |    7 | 2013-10-28 |      236


table project
 id  |projecttype_id| description |            name
-----+--------------+-------------+----------------------------
 235 |            1 |             | Project_name1
 236 |            1 |             | Project_name2
 237 |            1 |             | Project_name3
 238 |            1 |             | Project_name4

table task
  id  |  work_id    | taskengine_id | severity | project_id
------+-------------+---------------+----------+----------
 8536 |         294 |             1 | 0        |      235
 8926 |         294 |             1 | 2        |      235
 8458 |         293 |             1 | 3        |      235
 8459 |         293 |             1 | 3        |      235
 8460 |         293 |             1 | 2        |      235
 8461 |         293 |             1 | 2        |      235
 8462 |         293 |             1 | 0        |      235
 8463 |         293 |             1 | 2        |      235
 8464 |         293 |             1 | 0        |      235
 8465 |         293 |             1 | 3        |      235
```

I would like to execute query which will count `tasks` divided into severity category.  but the main criteria however is to count only task from the most recent one `work` I mean with the latest date from `work.starttime`.

I Have a query which look like:

```
select p.name as pname,
count(case when t.severity = '0' then 1 else null end) as zero, 
count(case when t.severity = '1' then 1 else null end) as one,  
count(case when t.severity = '2' then 1 else null end) as two,  
count(case when t.severity = '3' then 1 else null end) as three 
from project p, task t 
where p.id = t.project_id 
group p.name 
order p.name;
```

However this way I am getting list of `Projects` with `Task`'s from all time, i would like to get only one which are related to the most recent work starttime. Could anyone give me some hint how I can adjust my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join with the max startime,

```
w.starttime = (SELECT max(starttime) from work w1 where w1.id = t.work_id)
```

then

```
select p.name as pname,
count(case when t.severity = '0' then 1 else null end) as zero, 
count(case when t.severity = '1' then 1 else null end) as one,  
count(case when t.severity = '2' then 1 else null end) as two,  
count(case when t.severity = '3' then 1 else null end) as three 
from project p, task t, work w
where p.id = t.project_id 
and  p.id= w.project_id
and w.starttime = (SELECT max(starttime) from work w1 where w1.id = t.work_id)
group p.name 
order p.name;
```

Comment: Somehow I get exactly same result as the query in the question, to be honest I don't knew how it is possible but the number's of severities are exactly the same ;(

Comment: rught the query is wrong i didn't see the "work.scid"...how scid is related to task? scid is the only field changin according to date..

Comment: `scid` is not related to `task` nor `project` it is only information who put certain `work` into db relation between work and task is `work.id = task.work_id`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you would only like to count tasks from most recent work of each project.

If so, would the query below do the job for you?

```
select p.name as pname,
 count(case when t.severity = '0' then 1 else null end) as zero, 
 count(case when t.severity = '1' then 1 else null end) as one,  
 count(case when t.severity = '2' then 1 else null end) as two,  
 count(case when t.severity = '3' then 1 else null end) as three 
 from project p, task t, work w
   where p.id = t.project_id
   AND w.id = t.work_id
   AND w.id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (project_id) id
    FROM work
    ORDER BY project_id, starttime DESC
   )
 group BY p.name 
 order BY p.name;
```

I only added the part, where you filter out only the most recent work for each project.